# PLC4X:Exception during scraping of Job

Tags: apache-plc4x, plc4x

I'm actually developing a project that read data from 19 PLCs Siemens S1500 and 1 modicon. I have used the scraper tool following this tutorial:

[PLC4x scraper tutorial](https://plc4x.apache.org/users/tools/scraper.html)

but when the **scraper** is working for a little amount of time I get the following exception:

[image]

I have changed the scheduled time between 1 to 100 and I always get the same exception when the **scraper** reach the same number of received messages.

I have tested if using PlcDriverManager instead of PooledPlcDriverManager could be a solution but the same problem persists.

In my pom.xml I use the following dependency:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.plc4x</groupId>
            <artifactId>plc4j-scraper</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

I have tried to change the version to an older one like 0.6.0 or 0.5.0 but the problem still persists.

If I use the modicon (Modbus TCP) I also get this exception after a little amount of time.

Anyone knows why is happening this error? Thanks in advance.

**Edit**: With the **scraper** version 0.8.0-SNAPSHOT I continue having this problem.

**Edit2**: This is my code, I think the problem can be that in my **scraper** I am opening a lot of connections and when it reaches 65526 messages it fails. But since all the processing is happenning inside the lambda function and I'm using a PooledPlcDriverManager, I think the scraper is using only one connection so I dont know where is the mistake.

```
 try {
        // Create a new PooledPlcDriverManager
        PlcDriverManager S7_plcDriverManager = new PooledPlcDriverManager();


        // Trigger Collector
        TriggerCollector S7_triggerCollector = new TriggerCollectorImpl(S7_plcDriverManager);

        // Messages counter
        AtomicInteger messagesCounter = new AtomicInteger();


        // Configure the scraper, by binding a Scraper Configuration, a ResultHandler and a TriggerCollector together
        TriggeredScraperImpl S7_scraper = new TriggeredScraperImpl(S7_scraperConfig, (jobName, sourceName, results) -> {
            LinkedList<Object> S7_results = new LinkedList<>();

            messagesCounter.getAndIncrement();

            S7_results.add(jobName);
            S7_results.add(sourceName);
            S7_results.add(results);

            logger.info("Array: " + String.valueOf(S7_results));
            logger.info("MESSAGE number: " + messagesCounter);

            // Producer topics routing
            String topic = "s7" + S7_results.get(1).toString().substring(S7_results.get(1).toString().indexOf("S7_SourcePLC") + 9 , S7_results.get(1).toString().length());
            String key = parseKey_S7("s7");
            String value = parseValue_S7(S7_results.getLast().toString(),S7_results.get(1).toString());
            logger.info("------- PARSED VALUE -------------------------------- " + value);

            // Create my own Kafka Producer
            ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<String, String>(topic, key, value);

            // Send Data to Kafka - asynchronous
            producer.send(record, new Callback() {
                public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata recordMetadata, Exception e) {
                    // executes every time a record is successfully sent or an exception is thrown
                    if (e == null) {
                        // the record was successfully sent
                        logger.info("Received new metadata. \n" +
                                "Topic:" + recordMetadata.topic() + "\n" +
                                "Partition: " + recordMetadata.partition() + "\n" +
                                "Offset: " + recordMetadata.offset() + "\n" +
                                "Timestamp: " + recordMetadata.timestamp());
                    } else {
                        logger.error("Error while producing", e);
                    }
                }
            });



        }, S7_triggerCollector);
        

        S7_scraper.start();
        S7_triggerCollector.start();


        } catch (ScraperException e) {
            logger.error("Error starting the scraper (S7_scrapper)", e);
        }
```

Comment: Hi ... sorry for the late response ... could you please try with version 0.8.0-SNAPSHOT. We recently fixed a lot of problems with the 0.7.0 branch. Perhaps the issues is already fixed in the soon to be released 0.8.0.

Comment: @ChristoferDutz Hi, and thanks for the answer. With 0-8-0-SNAPSHOT I continue having the same problem. I dont know if in the code I show I have done something wrong or if there is another problem

Comment: Ok ... I think your second edit might have disclosed the issue ... this is almost the max of a 2 byte value which is used as "transaction-identifier" (Internally we start at id 10) if you take this into account this is a perfect mach with what you observe ... So theoretically it should start back at 0 ... I just updated the driver ... so could you please try again (give the system a few minutes to update the SNAPSHOTs however ;-) )

Comment: @ChristoferDutz Hi, sorry for the very late response but I hadnt access to the PLCs. I have tested the version 0.8.0 and the problem is solved. The scrapper is working properly.

Answer (score 1):

So in the end indeed it was the PLC that was simply hanging up the connection randomly. However the NiFi integration should have handled this situation more gracefully. I implemented a fix for this particular error ... could you please give version 0.8.0-SNAPSHOT a try (or use 0.8.0 if we happen to have released it already)

Comment: I will try the new version as soon as possible (I dont know if I will have access to my university plcs theses days. I will write here with the results.

Comment: By the way ... the 0.8.0 has been released recently.

Comment: Sorry for not answering before. I only could realize some fast tests with scrapper 0.7 and still have problems but I wasnt sure if the problem was in the scrapper because I hadnt time to test it properly so I decided not to post until I can test it properly. When I test the 0.8 version I will write here. Thanks.